# TomCat apache 6 Installation - Error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have to implement an Java application in our productin environment.
As a prerequitie, I was asked to install Tomcat Apache 6.0/MySql to run the application.

Followed the Steps:
1. Installed the JDK 8 Update 161 (64bit)
2. Downloaded the Tomcat Apache 6.0 [apache-tomcat-6.0.0] from the site tomcat.apache.org
[image]
3. Installed the Tomcat Apache.
[image]
4. checked the services that Tomcat Apache server is up and running
5. Created the Environment Variable JAVA_HOME
6. Copied the source code[4 folders] supplied by vendors and renamed according to document.
7.Modified the Tomcat->Conf->server.xml for context path
8.Modified the Tomcat->Conf->web.xml for default welcome page for the application.

Error:
HTTP Status 404
type Status report
description The requested resource (localhost:8081/GeoCMS/) is not available.

[image]

Query:
1. Is it enough just copy the vendor supplied folder in Tomcat6.0->webapps?
Will the application can run just like that after copying?Or any deployment needed like in Visual Studio?
[image]

2. The version of the JDK is right for the Tomcat apache 6.0?

3.Am I left anything?

Comment: tomcat 6 support java 5 and later so no problem with jdk 8, try to start tomcat without your project

Comment: Go to `logs` folder and check out recent entries in `catalina.out`. There might be something useful. Your problem is probably related to incorrect configuration.

Comment: OMG: Tomcat has seen its end of life in 2016. You seem to have downloaded 6.0.0, which was published in 2006. This is not the version you want to run. If you *really* have to go with 6.0, at least take the *last* release, not the first one. Also, stackoverflow is for programming related questions, installing random applications is out of scope here. I'd recommend to check with the software vendor whos application you're installing

Comment: @OlafKock Slight typo I think - it's Tomcat *6* that was end of life'd in 2016. Tomcat itself is still going strong! But I quite agree, there's absolutely no excuse to be using Tomcat 6 anymore, let alone in a *new* install.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've been missing the "6". *Tomcat 6* has seen its end of life in 2016. But no typo with 6.0.0: The screenshot shows that 6.0.0, which was published in 2006 (two-thousand-and-six), is in use. There's no excuse for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply-Azzabi Haythem,Micheal Dz, Olaf Kock, Berry 120.Noted the point Tomcat Apache 6. I downloaded the Tomcat 7.0 and facing the same issue. The steps followed to configure the Tomcat, Is it right one? or Am I missing steps. If possible kindly share installation steps for installing and configuring the Tomcat. Query: Just copy the project folders in the webapp  will the run the application?

Comment: Why can't you look into the logs? It's what every developer should do in the first place.